# Pasting from system clipboard in insert mode and then repeat (.) fails

Tags: vim, clipboard, paste

I'm in in MacVim, but I'm guessing this applies to gVim as well. In insert mode, if I paste from the system clipboard <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> then get out <kbd>Esc</kbd> then repeat <kbd>.</kbd> all it does is move the cursor back a space. It's not registering the system paste as part of the keystrokes I typed.

Strangely, if I type <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> in normal mode, I can hit <kbd>.</kbd> after to repeat it and it works fine.

I know I could type `<c-r>*`, but that is **bad**.

I tried `inoremap <D-v> <c-r>*` but it seemed to have no effect.

Comment: Can't confirm. I'm able to use `.` to repeat my pasted and/or inserted text. Try starting vim with `vim -u NONE` and attempt to reproduce.

Comment: happens with -u NONE as well (and it did remove my settings etc). Vim 7.3.390

Comment: Let me take back my comment. I can replicate this in MacVim.

Comment: What's interesting is if you go into insert mode, then `<C-v>`, then `<D-v>`, you get the pasted string with a `<BS>` inserted before it!

Comment: I'm in macvim as well* that's the version. And that is interesting.

Comment: This _doesn't_ happen for me in vim in the terminal, but does happen in MacVim.

Comment: two keystrokes ingrained in everyone's muscle memory is always better than four random keystrokes, and I'm in insert mode. Also, here in the future we have these things called guis, which you grow to expect to integrate nicely with your os

Comment: OK. One more test, this time at the office with gVim on WinXP. It works with `S-Ins`.

Comment: do you mean s-ins works and c-v doesn't? or they both work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting this in your ~/.gvimrc:

```
inoremenu Edit.Paste <C-r><C-p>*
```

Comment: This won't work because it doesn't `:set paste` which apparently `Edit.Paste` does behind the scenes

Comment: Okay then `<C-r><C-p>*`